# footer disappearing in Opera (11.63)

Tags: html, css, opera

I have a footer stuck to the bottom of my site by setting the wrapper min-height to 100%, the position of the footer to absolute with this CSS -

```
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:250px;
    min-height:250px;
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(../images/footerback.png);
    border-top:2px groove #FFF;
    bottom:0px;
    margin-bottom:-250px;

}
```

Problem seems to occur sporadically and can be recreated by any zooming in Opera (footer completely disappears).

Site - http://www.simplerweb.co.uk/

Comment: Shouldn't it be `margin-top` to pull it back up from the bottom of the page, rather than lower it below? Then you'll need 250px od `padding-bottom` for the container too.

Comment: I seem to have fixed it by just removing the margin altogether and adding 250px padding to a class below the content div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see any problems in opera but your css has some unnecessary code in it.  This below will have the same results:

```
#footer {
    min-height:250px;
    background-image:url(../images/footerback.png);
    border-top:2px groove #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be your margin-bottom causing that. Need to recode depending on how you want your footer to behave eg. fixed to the bottom, bottom of the page.

Comment: Ah yes, it was the margin!

How do I fix that and still keep the footer at the bottom and not overlapping the content?

Comment: A div with a padding of the same height as the footer after the content seems to work?